# How did Vers know Agent Fury's name?

Tags: plot-explanation, marvel-cinematic-universe, captain-marvel

When Agent Fury met Vers at the phone-booth for the first time in *Captain Marvel*, she called him "Agent Fury", but he didn't introduce himself there, right? How did she know his name?

Answer (score 22, accepted):

He did introduce himself, actually. Not by *saying* his name, but by showing his identification​. Hence Vers' line:

> We don't carry our identification on little cards.

The "little card" contained various info but most importantly here, his name, which is how Vers was able to name him when she said:

> Congratulations agent Fury, you finally asked a relevant question.

For the record, here's a picture of Fury's ID, seen later in the movie. His name is partially hidden by the thumb, but this is what Vers saw:

[image: Fury's ID]

Comment: Well, this leaves the "Agent" half of "Agent Fury" unmotivated.

Comment: @EricTowers I guess any kind of "special force enforcer", with levels of clearance and all, may qualify as an Agent? Is that word spoken elsewhere in the movie, referring to StarForce for instance?

Comment: @EricTowers She is speaking English.  That "honorific for police-type person who isn't in the police" being "agent" isn't unreasonable.

Comment: @Yakk : The Kree don't appear to use such honorofics among themselves, so what is this social construct based upon?

Comment: @EricTowers automatic translation of sorts? Didn't she think her translator was jammed or something? Maybe it includes an IA of sorts that added the thing

Comment: @EricTowers Odds are Kree doesn't use "the", or English's tense system either.  A automatic Translator that isn't at least a bit telepathic (on at least the speaker) is going to suck; you cannot reliably/accurately/properly translate from a sentence in one language to a proper sentence in another using only the words spoken.  One language might have gendered pronouns, another doesn't; the words in the ungendered language do not say what the gender of the pronoun is.  Etc.  She is speaking fluent English, "Agent" would be obvious honorific there to a fluent English speaker.

Comment: @EricTowers Maybe she learned what agents are while growing up in the U.S., being a native speaker of American English, and being a U.S. Air Force pilot?

Comment: Well she didn't remember her past at that time. Only that she had a life on Earth. She was also using a universal translator to speak English. (She mentioned it while talking to security guard who was in the car.)